# Ember 1.0.0 - can no longer access controller from view?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using a `render` helper inside a template, which renders a searchbox with a typeahead.

Essentially (code removed for brevity):

```
script(type='text/x-handlebars', data-template-name='index')
    {{render search}}

script(type='text/x-handlebars', data-template-name='search')
    {{view App.TaggableInput valueBinding="searchText"}}
```

Which gives me a `SearchController` separated from the `IndexController`.

Inside `App.TaggableInput` I'm grabbing `searchController` to do some checking on the keyUp event:

```
App.TaggableInput = Ember.TextField.extend({
    keyUp: function(e){
        var controller = this.get('controller');
        // Do stuff with the controller
    }
});
```

On Ember RC7, I can access the controller inside theview as you'd expect with `this.get('controller').get('searchText')`.

However in Ember 1.0.0 `this.get('controller')` returns the view, and whatever I do I can't get `searchController`.

I can't find any related info on the ember website regarding what's changed or what I'm supposed to do... for now I'm sticking with RC7.

Any ideas? I've spent hours on it this morning and can't figure it out. Thanks.

## UPDATE: Fixed!

I swapped out `this.get('controller')` for `this.get('targetObject')` and it works as before. Had a peruse through [a recent commit in ember source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/326af5a9c88df76f5effe11156a07b64c8b178a3#packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_support.js) to find it...

Thanks for your suggestions guys!

Comment: I have the same or a similar problem with 1.0.0. I guess that `this.get('controller')` gives you the implicilty created `TaggableInputController` and not the controller of your current route. But it's just a guess.

Comment: `Ember.TextField` used to extend `View`.  Unless otherwise specified, a `View`'s `controller` defaults to `parentView.controller`.

As of Ember 1.0.0, `Ember.TextField` extends `Component`.  A `Component` doesn't have a controller but rather has a `targetObject`.  

Thats why your solution works!

Comment: I have an ember app with a `text-input` component subclassing the `Ember.TextField` one, and a `select-input` component that subclasses the `Ember.Select` class. However, in the `select-input` code I was able to access the controller with `this.get('controller')`, and in the `text-input` I needed to resort to the solution suggested in the UPDATE section above (`this.get('targetObject')`). I just wanted to comment about it here because it seems intereseting, and perhaps someone has some insight on the reasons for this.

Answer (score 5):

I guess that in your code

```
App.TaggableInput = Ember.TextField.extend({
    keyUp: function(e){
        var controller = this.get('controller');
        // Do stuff with the controller
    }
});
```

this line

```
 var controller = this.get('controller');
```

gets the controller associated to your (subview)

Try to use this line instead to access the route's controller:

```
 var controller = this.get('parentView.controller');
```

Comment: i have the same issue and i used the same approach (which works). but what has changed in ember 1.0 that causes this?

Comment: This fetches `indexController` for me, which is the parent of `searchController` :(

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the `{{render}}` helper takes 2 arguments, the first is the context, the second is the model.
I recommend using this method and following the naming convention for the model's controller rather than setting the controller explicitly.

You can find the docs here: 
http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper

Accessing controllers from views was also being tracked in this discussion: 
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1712#issuecomment-31183940

Answer (score 0):

I think Ember has not changed its behaviour. I created a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ipEpUPa/4/edit), where i managed to get the controller successfully.

What i did was creating a simple View and show it via `{{render}}` helper:

**View:**

```
App.FooView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    console.log(this.get("controller.constructor"));
    console.log(this.get("context.constructor"));
  }
});
```

**Template:**

```
{{render foo}}
```

And the first log statement showed an associated controller. Can you see any conceptual difference between my code and yours?